# IRB Documentation, Rails 4, Syntax Error, Params, Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, irb

I'm going to slip in a specific code question to illustrate my point, but my real concern is, where can find some translation or deeper explanation of how to use IRB and a good explanation of what the errors mean?

The error I'm getting in console:

> SyntaxError: (irb):10: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

I'm inexperienced in rails, but I think I understand what this says. Let me try:

"Syntax error, unexpected end of the line, expecting hash rocket" I assume this means I didn't correctly right out my params when I was creating a new Account and User/Owner.

I'm trying to create a new account and add the owner attribute at the same time, as it should work in my app. Below is the AccountController code related to my issue:

```
def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
        if @account.save
            sign_in(@account.owner)
            flash[:notice] = "Your account has been successfully created."
            redirect_to root_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "Sorry, your account could not be created."
            render :new
        end
end
```

And the params also in AccountController:

```
private
    def account_params
        params.require(:account).permit(:name, :subdomain,
            { owner_attributes: [ :email, :password, :password_confirmation
                ]}
        )
    end
```

This is how I entered it into console:

```
Account.create! name: "Cheese", subdomain: "cheesy", { owner_attributes: [ email: "email@real.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar" ]}
```

User is made by Devise in case that matters in this circumstance.

Frankly, even if I've translated this correctly, which I probably didn't, did I make the error in my original code or in the console? But back to my original question where is a good resource to figure out what the IRB error is telling me? If I Google this error as is the results only remotely relate to my concern. More specifically, Google seems to treat \n as "n" and => as nothing.

Here is the complete console transcript:

2.1.5 :002 > Account.create! name: "Cheese", subdomain: "cheesy", { owner_attributes: [ email: "email@real.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar" ]}
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
    from /home/reed/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/reed/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in`start'
    from /home/reed/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/reed/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
    from /home/reed/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:9:in`require'
    from bin/rails:9:in `'

Comment: Dave, thanks for checking it out. I added the full console transcript.

Answer (score 0):

`[ email: "email@real.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar" ]` is an array containing hashes.

The inner hashes need curly braces.

Comment: fylooi, is this what you mean: Account.create! name: "flat", subdomain: "line", {owner_attributes: [{email: "email@notreal.com"}, { password: "foobar"}, {password_confirmation: "foobar"}]}

Comment: That should be valid syntax, but i'm not sure whether ActiveRecord expects that or `{owner_attributes: {email: "email@notreal.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar"} }`

Comment: I tried the way I asked about in my comment and the way that you showed me in your most recent comment and I still have the same error.

Comment: Ah, I missed the earlier hashes. Try `create! name: "Cheese", subdomain: "cheesy", owner_attributes: { email: "email@real.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar" }`

Answer (score 0):

The response from fylooi was the correct one:

> Ah, I missed the earlier hashes. Try create! name: "Cheese", subdomain: "cheesy", owner_attributes: { email: "email@real.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar" } – fylooi

Thanks fylooi